# XNA Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys() returns "Kanji" as a default

Tags: c#, input, xna, keyboard

I am writing a simple utility class that converts XNA's `KeyboardState.Keys` enumeration into the corresponding char value so text can be typed in my game.

As a test, I used the following code to ensure that `Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys()` was correctly returning `Keys.None`, or an empty `Key[]`:

```
foreach (var item in Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys())
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Unfortunately, this is not what happened. The default for my keyboard seems to be `Keys.Kanji` for some strange reason.

I do have the default Microsoft Japanese keyboard/IME installed on this PC. However, I tried running it with and without it installed, and this does not seem to affect the problem at all.

*(Side note: **Terraria** is also written in XNA, and its keybindings also happen to suffer from this same issue.)*

---

**Edit**:

After testing with my PC, as well as two friends, it appears that on Windows 7, with a Japanese IME installed, XNA will erroneously(?) report the `Keys.Kanji` is being pressed at all times. It isn't a big deal since there is no change in state between `KeyboardState` objects, so it's workable. Weird!

One friend had Windows 7 without a Japanese IME, another was using Windows 8 with an IME, and I was the only one who seems to have had a problem.

Comment: But what exactly is the problem you are having? I get the enum to char is not working, but you are not showing any relevant code to check that functionality.

Comment: The problem is that XNA Keyboard.GetState().GetPressedKeys() returns “Keys.Kanji”... as per the title. I have no "Kanji" key on my keyboard. It returns a Keys[] array, and because I am pushing no buttons, it should return an empty array or else Keys.None.